# Is there a way to write a css to any div that contain specific string in its id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jQuery that sets style by div name:

```
$("[id*='_container']").css({"width":"100%"});
```

That name of the div can be XXXXX_container (its randomly generated).

Is there a way to write this in a css and not as jQuery code ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - why not use classes?

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/

Comment: can't use classes because this is Openlayers problem i'm trying to solve and when the map div inititated , it doesnt get class , only div id and inline style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's selector syntax is based off of [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

```
[id*="_container"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Really though you should be adding classes rather than selecting IDs like this:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors the MDN is more readable.

Comment: @iambriansreed, i agree, however I prefer to link to primary sources.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[id$="_container"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5TAxG/)**

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

Comment: @iambriansreed - How is it not the solution? OP wants all elements where the ID ends in "_container" which is exactly what this does, not to mention two other users posted the same answer.

Comment: You inferred that from the code and skipped the actual question.

Comment: @iambriansreed - what are you talking about? How did I skip the question?

Comment: @iambriansreed - plus, if you did upvote zzzzBov's answer, you upvoted one that's wrong. His answer will select all elements that contain "_container" anywhere in the ID, not only at the end.

Comment: You answered "Is there a way to write a css to any div that contain specific string **at the end** in its id?" not "Is there a way to write a css to any div that contain specific string in its id?". It's semantics I know but important when considering other use cases. Really wrong you would downvote without commenting when you disparaged others for the same thing.

Comment: @j08691, my answer was only to match the code as provided, and I really wish iambriansreed didn't drag me into this. Both selectors are probably the wrong answer because OP likely has an XY problem.

Comment: @iambriansreed - What? "Really wrong you would downvote without commenting when you disparaged others for the same thing". What are you talking about, I didn't downvote anyone.

Comment: @iambriansreed - When did I say you did?

Answer (score 1):

In css...

```
[id$="_container"] {
    /* your css */
}
```

'id$=' means an element whose id ends with.